# Merge two Json object with condition

Tags: c#, json

Is there any way to merge two JSON objects while comparing data, checking if the data is duplicated, and then selecting the one where `CreationTimeUtc`, `LastWriteTimeUtc` and `Length` is greater than the second?

```
if json1= [
  {
    "CreationTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:22 PM",
    "LastWriteTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:22 PM",
    "Name": "test1.txt",
    "Length": "1",
     "owner":"pc1"
  },
  {
    "CreationTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:16 PM",
    "LastWriteTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:16 PM",
    "Name": "test2.txt",
    "Length": "5" ,
    "owner":"pc1"
  }
];

json2=
[
  {
    "CreationTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:22 PM",
    "LastWriteTimeUtc": "9/21/2015 1:38:22 PM",
    "Name": "test1.txt",
    "Length": "1",
    "owner":"pc2"
  },
  {
    "CreationTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:16 PM",
    "LastWriteTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:16 PM",
    "Name": "test2.txt",
    "Length": "4" ,
    "owner":"pc2"
  }
]
result=
[
  {
    "CreationTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:22 PM",
    "LastWriteTimeUtc": "9/21/2015 1:38:22 PM",
    "Name": "test1.txt",
    "Length": "1",
    "owner":"pc2"
  },
  {
    "CreationTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:16 PM",
    "LastWriteTimeUtc": "9/20/2015 1:38:16 PM",
    "Name": "test2.txt",
    "Length": "5" ,
    "owner":"pc1"
  }
]
```

Comment: is this suppose to be pseudo code ?

Comment: this example for the inputs and the output  that  i need

Comment: Is there any magical force preventing you from writing your own unique merging algorithm and comming back with a *specific* problem? Because this is not the way Stack Overflow works; read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft's JSON.NET library and LINQ.

The following code deserializes to anonymous objects (you can use strongly-typed objects as well). Combines the two lists, groups them by "Name" attribute and takes the first item in each group that has the maximum dates and length.

If you have different business rules (such as dates are greater but length is not) you can fiddle around with the code but this should be enough to get you started:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonString1 = File.ReadAllText("sample1.json");
    string jsonString2 = File.ReadAllText("sample2.json");
    var newType = new[] { new { CreationTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow, LastWriteTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow, Name = "", Length = "", owner = "" } };
    var json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString1, newType);
    var json2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString2, newType);
    var combined = json1.Union(json2);

    var results = from c in combined
            group c by c.Name into g
            select g.First(i => i.LastWriteTimeUtc == g.Max(m => m.LastWriteTimeUtc) &&
                                i.LastWriteTimeUtc == g.Max(m => m.LastWriteTimeUtc) &&
                                i.Length == g.Max(m => m.Length));

    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
{ CreationTimeUtc = 20/09/2015 13:38:22, LastWriteTimeUtc = 21/09/2015 13:38:22, Name = test1.txt, Length = 1, owner = pc2 }
{ CreationTimeUtc = 20/09/2015 13:38:16, LastWriteTimeUtc = 20/09/2015 13:38:16, Name = test2.txt, Length = 5, owner = pc1 }
```

Comment: always fun to see downvotes without explanations :-)